# Symfony2: PdoSessionHandler Error 'sess_lifetime'

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I have an application made with Symfony2 and I have a rarely problem, when I starts my application, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'sess_lifetime' in 'field list'

I don't know if the origin is any update or similar, but I haven't changed my code.

Anybody has an Idea?
Thanks!

Comment: According to [The Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html#configuring-the-table-and-column-names), "*The `db_lifetime_col` was introduced in Symfony 2.6. Prior to 2.6, this column did not exist.*"  Have you upgraded your version of Symfony from that with which the database was created?

Comment: Yes, I did a composer install and now I have this problem

Comment: See https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/UPGRADE-2.6.md#httpfoundation

Comment: Thanks @eggyal worked great!

Answer (score 0):

You may give a name to your column in the entity 
/src/Entity/Sessions.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="sess_lifetime", type="integer")
 */
 private $sessLifetime;
```